# How to fix increment button adds number to end of value instead of incrementing after onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to handle the increment of a button click via React.

What I am stumped on is that increment adds a value to the end of the number instead of actually incrementing it, whereas decrement works correctly. For instance I have a value of 30 that I added via the keyboard.  Then when I click on increment instead of 31, ends up being 301.

In my parent component I have:

```
state = {
    points: 0,
}  

updateInputValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({points : event.target.value})
}

handlePoints = (key) => {
    const { points } = this.state;

    if(key === 'increment')
        this.setState({ points: points + 1 })
    else
        points  > 0 && this.setState({ points: points - 1 })
};
```

And in the child:

```
<input
    type="number" 
    id="num_of_players" 
    name="Number of Players"
    min="0"   value= {this.props.points} onChange={evt => 
    this.props.updateInputValue(evt)}/>

<button
    width={`${BUTTON_WIDTH}px`} 
    fontSize={`${BUTTON_FONTSIZE}px`} 
    color='red' 
    onClick= {()=> this.props.handlePoints('increment')}><ImageContainer> 
    <Image><img src={ plusIconSVG } alt='plus button' /></Image> 
    </ImageContainer></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is think the issue is that it's using the string version of plus, which is concatenation. Reason this is happening is because the `event.target.value` variable is a string. Try wrapping with `parseInt`.